# Re-Directing IP Address to domain and keeping URL's the same

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We recently set our site live after developing it on a temporary URL which looked like this:

214.254.325.33/website.com/

Now the site is live, but the temporary URL has been indexed and we would like all the requests for the temp URL to be re-directed to the correct page, so these:

```
214.254.325.33/website.com/a-new-page
214.254.325.33/website.com/a-new-page2
214.254.325.33/website.com/a-new-page3
```

Would become this:

```
www.website.com/a-new-page
www.website.com/a-new-page2
www.website.com/a-new-page3
```

Is this possible with HTAccess?

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^214\.254\.325\.33$
RewriteRule ^website\.com/(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it works for the homepage but when you try to go to an inner page I get a 403 error, so if I try to visit: 214.254.325.33/website.com/ it works - if I try 214.254.325.33/website.com/a-new-page3 I get a 403 Forbidden error. I'm on WordPress if that makes a difference?

Comment: If you are using Wordpress then make sure this rule is very first rule in your .htaccess and also make sure to use `www.website.com` in WP permalink settings (home and site URL)

Comment: Hmm strange, everything is setup like you said but I still get 403 errors :(

Comment: It is obvious that this rule has no instructions to add 403 any where. Do you have a .htaccess inside `/website\.com/` folder also?